# Fault Code - No Powertrain DTC's or Freeze Frame Data

Tags: maintenance, dodge, dtc

I have a 2013 Dodge Dart that is showing a fault code - no powertrain DTC's or freeze frame data is presently stored in vehicle. How can I get this fault code reset so my check engine light goes off?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please edit your question and put in it what it is you're trying to figure out? As it is stated, there's really no question there.

Comment: What fault code is displayed?